# IsPost is not working correctly

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am posting a form and checking it's completion using `IsPost` but I never get the result I want :

```
@if (IsPost)
{
    var error = false;
    var nom = Request["searchGroup"];
    if (nom.IsEmpty())
    {
        error = true;
        @:Fill the form <br />
            }
    if (!error)
    {
        Response.Redirect(Href("~/Search/FindGroups"), false);
    }
}

<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="~/Search/FindGroups">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" name="searchGroup" id="searchGroup"/>
    <button type="submit" id="searchValidate"> Rechercher </button><br />

</form>
```

So this is my form, when I post the form with an empty `<input>` it should show 'Fill the form' and not change page, but instead it redirects everytime. What am I not seeing?

Comment: if you dont want the form to reload then why not use Ajax?

Comment: @Usman Hmm, I don't know ajax very well, how would one do that?

Comment: @FlexabustBergson Use `$.ajax` & return `JsonResult` for that, and use `success` block in AJAX call to insert response data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you want to validate the textbox before form submission you can add `id` in from

```
<form class="form-inline" id="myform" method="post" action="~/Search/FindGroups">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" name="searchGroup" id="searchGroup"/>
    <button type="submit" id="searchValidate"> Rechercher </button><br />

</form>
```

and in `jquery` add this

```
$("#searchValidate").click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();
if($('#searchGroup').val() === "")
 {
   alert("Fill the form")
 }
else{
   $("#myform").submit();
 }
 });
```

and dont forget to add this in head

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/t04p54v4/